# Programmatically capture Chrome Async Javascript stack trace

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-devtools

I've been working on trying to add some better error logging to a web application that is only run on Chrome. In essence, I want to be able to capture and store stack traces. For synchronous code, this works fine, but for async code, I've run into something a tad strange. Essentially, Chrome appears to log additional information as part of its async stack trace feature, but I haven't been able to figure out how to capture it.

Code, to run in Chrome browser console:

```
let e;
let a = () => Promise.resolve(null)
.then(() => (null).foo)
.catch(err => {
  console.info(err); 
  console.error(err); 
  e = err;
})
let b = () => a();
let c = () => b();
c();
```

Output:

```
(info)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null
    at <anonymous>:3:20

(error, after expanding)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null
    at <anonymous>:3:20
(anonymous) @ VM1963:6
Promise.catch (async)
a @ VM1963:4
b @ VM1963:9
c @ VM1963:10
(anonymous) @ VM1963:11
```

So `console.error` gives me a stack trace threaded all the way through the callstack, presumably through some form of Chrome engine magick. `console.info` gives me the actual stack trace that's stored on `err`. If after this is all done I attempt to read the value of `e`, its stack is the two lines I get from the `console.info` statement, not the `console.error` statement.

What I'm asking is, is there any way to capture and store the async stack trace that Chrome is generating and using when I call `console.error`?

Comment: I tried it and I see that the error stack is displayed by chrome....It doesn't have anything to do with the error object being passed inside catch block

Comment: Have you considered using `Object.defineProperty` to override the `console` methods. Or similarly using `Proxy` to capture the `console` calls?

Answer (score 2):

`console.error()` seems to invoke `console.trace()` as a matter of convenience.

It doesn't look like a script can get the stack trace as anything other than a string. That string can be had with, for example, `err.stack`. MDN has documentation for the [`stack` property of `Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack). It's not part of a spec but seems to be supported across all platforms.

Comment: More to that, there's https://ghub.io/stacktrace-parser package, able to turn stringy stack to properly parsed list, cross-platform.

The problem is that `err.stack` doesn't include the async part, whereas the `console.trace` does. Node has `--async-stack-traces` flag for that. So the question is - if there's any way to get async stack trace in browser, like we see that in devtools.

Comment: [`--async-stack-traces`](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Sy_kBIJGP0XT34V1CV3nkWya4TwYx9L3Yv45LdGB6Q/edit#) is a v8 flag so may also be available in Chrome. You might also be interested in [StackTrace.JS](https://www.stacktracejs.com/) though, since it's based on `Error.stack`, it probably doesn't handle asynchronous stacks either.

Comment: Yes, npm's `stacktrace-js` also doesnt include the async part.